# pinia store gets updated but not showing in view

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, vue-reactivity

In the code below, I have a problem with `foobar` which is an array of objects that I get from an API and that is stored in a `ref` in a pinia store.

I import it into a parent component via `storeToRefs`. One sibling component contains a form for adding an object to `foobar`. That method and the argument (the form) is sent to the parent component.

Another sibling of that parent component displays the objects contained in `foobar` with v-for.

When an object is added, it shows up in the pinia store, but not in the view.

```js
// pinia store
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { getData } from '@/composables/useApi'

const foobar = ref([])

const spendings = computed(() => {
// this computed property gets update well
    return [...foobar.value].filter((obj) => {
      return obj.montant < 0
    })
  })

const get_foobar = async (id, month, year) => {
    try {
      const response = await getData.get(
        `/use/b/accounts/${id}/${month}/${year}`
      )
      if (response.status === 200) {
        foobar.value = response.data.accounts
        return true
      }
      return false
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.response.data
    }
  }

const update_foobar = (entree) => {
    foobar.value.push({
        id: entree.id,
        blabla: entree.blabla
    })
}
```

In the component I do:

```html
<template>
<!-- parent template with 2 siblings -->

      <TheAddOperationModal
        :open="additionnalOperation"
        @close="close"
        @add_foobar="add_foobar"
      />

     <TheAccountLines
         :foobar="foobar"
         @select="select"
         @edit="edit"
         @delete="delete"
     />

</template>
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
const { foobar } = storeToRefs(MyStore)
const {  update_foobar} = AccountStore

const TheAddOperationMOdal = defineAsyncComponent({
  loader: () => import('@/components/TheAddOperationModal.vue'),
  loadingComponent: TheLoadingComponent,
})


const TheAccountLines = defineAsyncComponent({
  loader: () => import('@/components/TheAccountLines.vue'),
  loadingComponent: TheLoadingComponent,
})

const add_foobar = (abc) => {
    // do various things with abc, including push to API via axios
    update_foobar(data) // data is data received from API corresponding to abc
}
</script>
```

In the vuejs devtools the data object gets added to the array of objects that is `foobar` but this doesn't show on the page (screen) ; although when I manually delete or add data to `foobar` in the pinia store in the devtools, it is reactive as objects do get added or deleted from the screen.

Comment: This needs additional context. Can you show more of your store logic so we can see how state and actions are constructed? Is `foobar` a property in your component markup? It should be computed if you want reactive updates.

Answer (score 0):

From this it seems you have not actually created a Pinia store but instead defined a few functions and variables almost like a composable. This is working partially in the same scope. You are not actually using Pinia at any point however.

You can implement this in 2 ways. The first looks more like a setup function. With this syntax refs are translated to state, computed become getters, and functions become actions.

```
export const useAccountStore = defineStore('account', () => {
const foobar = ref([]);

const spendings = computed…

async function get_foobar(id,month,year){…};

function update_foobar(entree){…};
});

return {foobar, spendings, get_foobar, update_foobar}
```

Component:

```
import {useAccountStore} from “./path/to/store”
const store = useAccountStore();
const foobar = computed(() => {
 return store.foobar.value}
);
const add_foobar = (abc) => {
store.update_foobar(data)
};
```

The second method looks more like a vuex store where you clearly define your state, getters, and actions:

```
export const useAccountStore = defineStore('account', () => {
state: () => ({
 return {
 foobar: ref()
})
getters: {spendings(){this.foobar}}

actions: {update_foobar(entree){this.foobar}}
```

Component logic is the same. Both cases also assume you have any initialized Pinia correctly with `createPinia` in your `main.js` file.